# Using Soft UART - how include library

Tags: library, uart

I want to use the soft serial communication example.

[image]

But when I compile it, it sais:

```
/home/xxx/Arduino/SoftwareSerialExample/aa/aa.ino:28:28: schwerwiegender Fehler: SoftwareSerial.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Kompilierung beendet.
exit status 1
Fehler beim Kompilieren für das Board Arduino Uno.
```

What is going there?
I  have a directory also with AFSoftSerial.h at /Arduino/libraries/AFSoftSerial/AFSoftSerial

Comment: the library should be here /home/xxx/.arduino15/packages/arduino/hardware/avr/1.8.6/libraries/SoftwareSerial

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure you have the line:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
```

... at the top of your Sketch.

Also, compare your code with that found on the [Arduino Software Serial Library web page here](https://docs.arduino.cc/learn/built-in-libraries/software-serial).

Finally, make sure your Arduino Application and all your Arduino Libraries are up to date.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a directory also with AFSoftSerial.h at /Arduino/libraries/AFSoftSerial/AFSoftSerial

The code is looking for the "SoftwareSerial" library and that is the library you need include and call, not "AFSoftSerial". Or, if you intend to use AFSoftSerial, then change your code to say that instead.

Answer (score -1):

Download [Arduino SoftwareSerial library](https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/tree/master/libraries/SoftwareSerial), extract it and put it into your libraries folder. Libraries folder is in your project folder. If you haven't changed project folder in Preferences, it will be in C:\Users\your_username\Documents\Arduino. Be careful that there are not two SoftwareSerial folders.
Then try to upload your code again.

Comment: just no. the Arduino SoftwareSerial library is bundled with the AVR boards package

Comment: But the compiler said "No such file or directory". Which means that the library is not installed anywhere.

Comment: which means something went wrong with the boards package installation and just putting random SoftwareSerial library into the libraries folder will not fix it